# what is the difference between the team site and project site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, project-site

I am new to SharePoint. I have researched something about the team site and project site as per my practical knowledge on team site and project site. I didn't find any difference.

What is the difference between the team site and project site? when to use the project site and team site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on 1st look, they look same but their is some differences, I.e.

- Project Site has all the collaborative features as in team site
- But Project site have Project Summary Web parts which is connected to the default task list (we can change it to any task list).
- Visual timeline of the project’s tasks.
- Project task schedule.
- Library for storing relevant project documents.
- Notebook for quickly capturing and organizing information about the
  project.
- Shared calendar for team events.

If you are managing the smaller projects then project site template will be best but for larger you have to use the Project Server / Project online or Project professional.

On other hand, if you want to use SharePoint for collaborative purpose then use the team site instead.

here are couple of links for detailed explanations:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-templates-to-create-different-kinds-of-SharePoint-sites-449eccec-ff99-4cf3-b62e-dcfee37e8da4#__bkmkdescriptionstart

https://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-blog/understanding-sharepoint-2013-project-site-template/

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the above answers are certainly precise. Use a Project Site if you want a Task List tied to a Project Timeline view. If you don't need a timeline on your site landing page (or wherever else you might show a task list) then you can always just add a Task List app.

In practice the only real difference is which features are turned on by default. Any Team Site can quickly be turned into a Project Site by activating the Project Functionality and Site Notebook features in the Site Features  (/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx)

Note - you'll need elevated permissions to access the Site Features

Answer (score 4):

The project site template is designed to help you plan the work that needs to be done, collaborate with teammates, and collect project files and documents.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/get-started-with-a-project-site-8b68274b-622d-4a99-9245-1d205897cd43

The team site used to store and collaborate on files or to create and manage lists of information. On a team site home page, you can view links to important team files, apps, and web pages and see recent site activity in the activity feed

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-is-a-sharepoint-team-site-75545757-36c3-46a7-beed-0aaa74f0401e

Answer (score 1):

As the above replies, you can also check the follows.

**Project Sites:**

1. Project Sites has "Project Functionality" Site Feature activate by default.
2. A Project Summary WebPart is added to the main page by default.
3. Project Sites had "Task" list added to it by default.

**Team Sites:**

1. Team Sites has "Wiki Page Home Page" Site Feature activate by default. "Project Functionality" Feature is not active by default.
2. Project Summary WebPart or any Timeline webpart can be added to the site.
3. Team Sites had "Team Task" list added to it by default.